# Super button not working after updating Ubuntu 18.04.3, Gnome 3.28.2

Tags: 18.04, gnome

After an update "Super" button stopped working. 
Installed "Tweak", changed to right super, changed back to right super.
Restarted the system. Nothing worked so far.

Super button is not visible when I open the "Keyboard" app trying to bind Super button to something.

Ubuntu 18.04.3, Gnome 3.28.2

Comment: Question unclear. What are you unable to do with the Super key that you could do before?

Comment: It does nothing now. It's like it's turned off. Nothing happens when I press it, can't use it to define any keyboard combination. Nothing.